# truncate double value to 6 decimal places

Tags: java, math, truncate

I was solving a problem which requires the output to be truncated and to my surprise I haven't been able to find a way to truncate numbers in java.

The output needs to be the a number followed by 6 decimal places.

What I want is
`double truncate(double number,int places)` and the output to be
`truncate(14/3.0) = 4.666666`.

but what I'm getting is

```
public static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, places);
    value = value * factor;
    long tmp = Math.round(value);
    return (double) tmp / factor;
  }
// rounds( 14/3.0 , 6 ) = 4.666667
```

With `String.format` I get

```
String.format("%.6f", 14/3.0) = 4.666667
```

I also tried a solution that I found on stackoverflow that suggested using BigDecimal and that gave me the very same answer.

`NumberFormat` also seems to work in the same way

```
java.text.NumberFormat f = java.text.NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
f.setMinimumFractionDigits(6);
System.out.println(f.format(14/3.0)); // 4.666667
```

Is there a built in method that does this or do I need to write my own using something like BigInteger?
Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you are not truncating but rounding:

```
long tmp = Math.round(value);
```

If you use a cast instead it should work:

```
long tmp = (long) value;
```

So the code below outputs `4.666666` as you expect:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(truncate(14/3.0, 6));
}

public static double truncate(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, places);
    value = value * factor;
    long tmp = (long) value;
    return (double) tmp / factor;
}
```

Comment: I want a double value how does casting to long help?

Comment: @nikhil in your `round` method, doing the replacement I suggest turns the method into the `truncate` method you are looking for.

Comment: You can also use `Math.floor`.

Comment: @starblue Yup, `long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, places); return (double) Math.floor(value * factor) / factor;` works too.

Answer (score 1):

Doubles don't have decimal places, ergo you can't truncate to any specific number of them. They have binary places. If you need a specific decimal representation, use `DecimalFormat` or `BigDecimal.`

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code helped me in restricting the number of decimal places (truncating) for a double value.

```
public static Double truncate (double valueToTruncate, int numberOfDecimalPlaces) {

if (valueToTruncate > 0) {
    return new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(valueToTruncate)).setScale(numberOfDecimalPlaces, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR).doubleValue();
} else {
    return new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(valueToTruncate)).setScale(numberOfDecimalPlaces, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING).doubleValue();
}
```

}

Hope this helps someone :)